# drawing a div on top of the rest without using absolute positioning

Tags: css

I have the following code

```
<div id="header" class="row">
    <ul id="topnav">
        <li>
            <a href="#">a</a>
            <span><a href="#">aa</a> <a href="#">ab</a></span>            
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">b</a>
            <span><a href="#">ba</a> <a href="#">bb</a></span>
        </li>
        <li style="float: right;"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="login_container">
        <form method="post" id="login_form">
            <table>login form</table>
        </form>

        <form method="post" id="create_account_form">
            <table>create account form</table>
        </form>
    </div>    
</div>

<div id="content">
content here
</div>
```

The header is about 60px tall and 960px wide, centered in the browser window and sticking to the top of the viewport. When the user clicks on "Login" the #login_container reveals itself. However, I want to position it aligned right with the header row, not aligned to the right of the viewport. I can do that by not using 'position: absolute' when styling #login_container, however, then the login form gets cut-off because the containing #header div is not tall enough. In other words, I want the #login_container aligned with the right edge of #header, but laid on top of #content, if any.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean..
Do you want the login container to be aligned to the right side of #header and to cover both #header and #content?

Comment: No, I want it to cover #content, but aligned to the right and bottom edge of #header. So, it would appear as a drop-down panel.

Comment: are you trying to do this without using javascript, or can the solution include some scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either set

```
#header {
 position: relative;
 height: 60px;
}
#login_container {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 60px; /* equal to #header height, if it's not fixed, you should retrieve it dynamically via jQuery */
}
```

and then dynamically retrieve #content's size and apply it to #login_container.

Otherwise, and maybe even better, you could wrap the whole code in a #container div, set its width to whatever width you wish the site to have, set it centered, then move #login_container from inside #header to immediately after it and with absolute position. You will have a cleaner css code and less meddling to do with jQuery (just setting login_container's height).. so it should be like this (if I'm not missing anything):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
#login_container { 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
#content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
</style>
<!--[if lte IE 6]><style type="text/css"></style><![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header" class="row">
        <ul id="topnav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">a</a>
                <span><a href="#">aa</a> <a href="#">ab</a></span>            
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">b</a>
                <span><a href="#">ba</a> <a href="#">bb</a></span>
            </li>
            <li style="float: right;"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <div id="login_container">
        <form method="post" id="login_form">
            <p>login form</p>
        </form>

        <form method="post" id="create_account_form">
            <p>create account form</p>
        </form>
    </div>    

    <div id="content">
    content here
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Give it a try and let me know if you still got problems!

Comment: oh, just one more note: if you float to the right your Login button/link, you should put it before the other form elements in your code, in order for it to be aligned with the other form elements, and not on the line below.

Comment: yes, that did it. Many thanks. The trick was to have the containing container with position relative, and then have stuff inside it with position absolute.